# Why does "bananas" mean "crazy"?

Tags: etymology

I wanted to know how and when the word "bananas" came to be associated with "crazy". There was nothing detailed on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bananas), but thanks to OED, I came to know that [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_underworld_speaks.html?id=xBkFAQAAIAAJ) is the origin of this usage.

I haven't been able to figure out the reason behind the usage, though. Is it arbitrary? Is it a random usage made popular by others, like videos that go viral on social networks?

PS: Incidentally, the use of "jerk" to mean *a fool* also originates from the same text.

Comment: The complete opposite is also true in cases like **second banana** and **top banana**.

Comment: The complete OED quote from that book ("He's bananas, he's sexually perverted; a degenerate.") makes me wonder if it's being used to mean "bent."

Comment: Maybe this sense of "go bananas" is related to "go ape".

Comment: http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?054 - this confirms the answer I've given below. (Assuming the link can be trusted, that is :P)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The 1935 definition in Albin Jay Pollock's *The Underworld Speaks* (apparently published by the FBI to help people spot gangsters by their speech) is:

> *He's bananas*, he's sexually perverted; a degenerate.

This may be alluding to *bent*, the shape of a banana.

*Bent* is 1914 US criminal slang meaning *dishonest* or *crooked*, and 1930 US slang meaning *illegal* or *stolen*.

The *eccentric*, *perverted* or *homosexual* meaning of *bent* may be originally UK slang; it appears in 1930 in Brophy and Partridge's *Songs and slang of the British soldier: 1914-1918* meaning *spoiled* or *ruined*. It soon after appears in 1942's *The American thesaurus of slang: a complete reference book of colloquial speech* in the definition for *eccentric*: "Balmy, bats, bent, [etc.]".

Another 1833 US slang meaning of *bent* is to intoxicated with alcohol or drugs.

The 1935 *bananas* is in brackets in the *OED*, so they're not convinced it is the same meaning.

---

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bananas) says the crazy meaning is much later: 1968. This year matches with the OED's third quotation from the University of South Dakota's *Current Slang*:

> *Bananas*, adj., excited and upset; ‘wild’.—College students, both sexes, Kentucky.—I'd say it, but everyone would just go *bananas*.

The OED's second quotation is from a 1956 Ohio newspaper caption:

> We heard the police broadcast!! They say you're bananas!!

But it's hard to gauge the exact meaning without seeing the picture.

---

Edit: I found a possible example of crazy *bananas* earlier than 1968 in *The Spokesman-Review* (Jun 22, 1962):

> I refer to the taunt, suspenseful, real-life drama NBC brought us from Oakmount Country Club over the weekend - the National Open. Compared to it, **Bonanza is bananas**, and Dr Bon Casey is just another pill-roll.

This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%27s%20bananas,she%27s%20bananas,they%20%27%20re%20bananas,go%20bananas,going%20bananas,gone%20bananas,went%20bananas&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests this meaning really took off in the early seventies:

[image: bananas]

Turning to slang dictionaries, *[The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms](http://books.google.fi/books?id=9re1vfFh04sC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=%22bananas%22%20dictionary%20slang&source=bl&ots=JHWzsB9o0k&sig=_gvWn-EDngvEl1uh58A87Ow_GHo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9BYJUK-yD8SK4gThma3oCg&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22go%20bananas%22&f=false)* (1997) says of *go bananas*:

> According to the lexicographer J. E. Lighter, this expression may allude to the similar *go ape*, in that apes and other primates are closely associated with eating bananas.

However, [*The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22bananas%22%20dictionary%20slang&source=bl&ots=cROsS0GYjo&sig=gbOvgML3h2dKEPqcmV0xUhCwjS4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9BYJUK-yD8SK4gThma3oCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bananas%22%20&f=false) (2007) says *bananas* (madly excited; mad; behaving oddly) is from 1957 and derives from *banana oil* (nonsense; persuasive talk) from 1924.

Contemporary synonyms are *horsefeathers* and *appleseauce*. The origins of *banana oil* are also unknown, but *[The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms](http://books.google.fi/books?id=9re1vfFh04sC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22banana%20oil%22%20slang&source=bl&ots=JHWzsBal_n&sig=BamqW8cGev3l_1PW5JXE6YKxbds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nxkJUOjIHIOI4gS5ib3hCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22banana%20oil%22%20slang&f=false)* (1997) says it's possibly variation on *snake oil* (quack medicine) extended to mean nonsense.

---

Edit 2: [*Green's Dictionary of Slang* Online](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/daqzu2a) has the noun back to 1957:

[image: S.F. News 30 Mar. 11: They say you’re bananas!!]

With * go bananas* from 1964 and *drive bananas* from 1975.

Comment: Good answer gets my vote. Partridge is one of my favoured sources.

Comment: Having checked my 2002 copy of Partridge's Dictionary of Slang, I see that the third definition under 'banana' states 'a foolish person; a softie since ca. 1950. Ex the softness of a ripe banana'. 'go bananas' dates from the US in 1974 (partially) and 1976 (widely).

Comment: Aaand now bananas sounds weird.

Comment: Here’s a clear usage with the “crazy” meaning in American English from 1964. It’s from a work of fiction and without further explanation, suggesting that the meaning is clear to the reader: “If I didn’t take a couple of drinks on Sundays, when I’m cooped up alone in those small-town motels, I’d go bananas.” — McCarthy, Joe, “Visit from Uncle Dave”, _This Week_ (Sunday magazine insert), Sunday, 29 November 1964, p. 9.

Comment: The rise in popularity of the usage in the 1970s might easily be attributed to the 1971 Woody Allen film, _Bananas_. The double-entendre was not ambiguous.

Comment: The OED “1956” caption seems specifically from a March 30/April 1, 1957 _Li’l Abner_ cartoon strip, by American cartoonist Al Capp, and the usage seems clearly to mean “crazy.” “Fearless Fosdick” is rejected as a candidate for experimental brain surgery because he’s “bananas.” The next frame explains, “We need first-class brains for our boys to practise on.”

Comment: See: “Boys Use Banana Oil to Inhale Fumes”, _Harrisburg Telegraph_ (Harrisburg, PA), September 27, 1921, p. 16.

Comment: “Banana Oil Has Kick”, _Harrisburg Telegraph_ (Harrisburg, PA), August 16, 1922, p. 1. “…banana oil for bootleg whisky and the customer ran amuck after sampling it.”

Comment: I don't think so.  The phrase is "go banana" but here its talking about banana.    Then, the meaning of the phrase is completely different.

Answer (score 8):

Of what I remember, it's because of how crazy monkeys become when they see bananas.

Comment: This evening as I was watching my young children "go bananas" after eating chocolate, I remembered this question and wondered whether bananas have a similar effect on monkeys, and whether this could be the origin of the term.

Answer (score 5):

Eric Partridge's *Dictionary of the underworld* mentions an earlier occurrence (1933) of the word meaning "sexually perverted": Ersine's *Underworld and Prison Slang* . Partridge also mentions the song [*Yes, we Have No Bananas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes!_We_Have_No_Bananas) (1920's).
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes!_We_Have_No_Bananas) gives a possible other origin of the phrase, mentioning cartoonist [Thomas A. Dorgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_A._Dorgan) as popularizing the phrase.
Not being a native English speaker I find it difficult to make a link between the phrase *Yes, we have no bananas* and *bananas* meaning *crazy*.
This explanation is more satisfying to my mind:
 ["during the late 1960s rumors spread across university campuses that roasted banana peels had psychedelic properties"](http://discovolonte.typepad.com/discovolonte/2007/12/the-mystery-of.html)

Comment: In some languages, when someone says something like "You don't have any bananas?", it's necessary to agree with the speaker and say "Yes, we have no bananas". In English, we agree with the grammar and say "No, we {have no / don't have any} bananas".

Answer (score 3):

There are some very nice references here and I don't mean to discredit them but rather show an opposing opinion (to the prevailing one of the sexual origin) possibly in part because I'm not completely convinced. So, biased I may be, I present the following website, which may lack creditably:

http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?054

It says that the term originates from giving a group apes a bunch of bananas and watching them go crazy eating them with "tremendous enthusiasm."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is related, but when I was growing up in Glasgow, a very common expression was: "Do you think I just got off the banana boat." It means "do you think I am stupid or gullible."

Etymologically, it is horribly racist. Glasgow was a major port for the British Empire, and the implication was someone who got off a boat delivering bananas, presumably from Africa or the Caribbean, was stupid or gullible. Perhaps due to a stereo type against black people, or perhaps due to a stereotype against people "from the colonies."

I have no idea if it is related, but someone else might have some thoughts on this.

Comment: Not being from Glasgow I couldn't definitively disagree with you, but in the US we have similar phrases ("just fell off the turnip truck", etc.) and they don't have anything to do with race or culture, but rather have to do with one having just arrived and not understanding local societal norms.

Comment: Partridge (again) in the Dic of Slang has 'banana boat' as an invasion boat ca. 1943+. An aircraft carrier 1940; and then later in the 1950s as a disparaging innuendo of illegal entry by, e.g. a West Indian in to Britain.

Comment: @Qube: Both the invasion and immigration ships are likely the same thing: cheap, shallow-draughted ships used by fruit companies to collect bananas from riverside plantations, later requisitioned during WWII. http://wordsonbooks.blogspot.com/2012/05/twelve-desperate-miles.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_boat_(ship)

Answer (score -1):

It might be related to Banana Republic.. I cannot really say for sure but then I have seen it being used for failed states/crazy form of government.

Comment: The idiom "banana republic" originally meant very specifically "Central American dictatorship financially dependent on the export of some resource (e.g. bananas)."  It is a historical allusion to the neocolonialist practices of the [United Fruit Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_fruit_company) in the middle of the 20th century.